# How to prove that if $x_n\to -\infty$ then $\frac{1}{x_n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, infinity

How to prove that if $x_n\to -\infty$ then $\frac{1}{x_n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

**My attempt:**

Let $x_n\to -\infty$ and $\epsilon\gt 0$. By the Archimedean Principle pick $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $N\gt \large\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. By taking the reciprocal, we can see that $x_n\ge N$ implies that $\large\frac{1}{x_n}\le \frac{1}{N}\lt \epsilon$. Therefore, since $\large\frac{1}{x_n}$ are all negative, we know that $\left|\large\frac{1}{x_n}\right|\lt \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.

This is a similar method I used on a similar problem and am not sure if it is really appropriate or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pedantic but complete proof. Pick any $\varepsilon>0$, and choose $N=N(\varepsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n<-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ whenever $n > N$. This is possible because $x_n \to -\infty$ as $n \to +\infty$. In particular, $x_n<0$ for every $n > N$.
For these $n$'s,
$$
-\varepsilon<\frac{1}{x_n}<0,
$$
and therefore $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{x_n}=0^{-}$.

Comment: Was it a necessary part of the proof? Or, is it alright to omit the line "This is possible because $x_n\to -\infty$ as $n\to +\infty$"?

Comment: It depends on the level at which you are working. At a high level, you can just say that $1/x_n$ is small because $x_n$ is large. But at an introductory level this would be rather unclear.